# Rails can't find image_magick gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, rubygems, imagemagick

I am trying to use image_magick gem to process image uploads, but rails can't locate it.

I have installed the gem successfully using:

```
gem install mini_magick-1.2.3.gem --local
gem update system
gem cleanup
```

and my model has

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mini_magick'
```

However, I still get the error:

```
no such file to load -- mini_magick
```

Can I add something to the environment.rb to point rails to the correct location?

Environment information:

```
Windows XP/InstantRails 2.0 
ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32]
Rails 2.3.2
```

Thanks for the help,

Comment: what does gem which mini_magick reveal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sanity check: does `gem list mini_magick` show the gem as installed?

Edit:

Just noticed that you have 'my model has...'; pull them out of the Model, and put the `require` lines into environment.rb.  You don't need `require 'rubygems'` if you're using Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Yes, it does:

    gem list mini_magick

    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    mini_magick (1.2.3)