# Unable to load gem in engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, runtime-error, rails-engines

I've got an engine that utilizes the `savon` gem. When I run the dummy application in `/test` inside the engine, it all works out just fine, but when I try to mount and run it as an engine inside my application, I get the error:

```
`require': no such file to load -- savon (LoadError)
```

I used to include it by adding `require "savon"` to the top of the model, `soap_model.rb` that uses it. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753383/rails-cant-find-image-magick-gem) post I shouldn't add it to the model, but the `environment.rb`. It did't seem like the `environment.rb` was run while starting the server, as it just produced a new error

```
uninitialized constant EngineName::SOAP::Savon
```

So I added it to an initializer, which yields the same error when trying to start the server with `rails s`.

Environment:

```
Mac OS 10.7.3
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
Rails 3.1.4
savon (0.9.9)
```

Note: I have of course made sure that bundle install runs correctly, and restarted the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem was included in the engines Gemfile, but not added as a dependency in the gemspec, thus it was not included when `bundle install` was run in the main app.

Adding this to `enginename.gemspec`

```
s.add_dependency "savon"
```

made everything work.

The reason it worked in the dummy app, is that it shares Gemfile with the engine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Gem is acting so weird, but you can try that code:

*You have first to **require** and then to **include** it.*

```
# config/initializers/application.rb
require 'savon'

include EngineName::SOAP::Savon
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, the problem is that it never reaches the `include` statement, as it crashes at the `require`. I still get `no such file to load`. The weird thing is that it works when running it in the dummy app, but not when mounted.